# What fields are available after parsing an email message?

Tags: python, email-parsing

I am using `email.message_from_string` to parse an email message into Python.  The documentation doesn't seem to say what standard fields there are.

How do I know what fields are available to read from, such as `msg['to']`, `msg['from']`, etc.?  Can I still find this if I don't have an email message to experiment with on the command line?

Comment: *how exactly is this done in command line if i do not have an incoming email to work with.* that is an entirely different question than what the title indicates, and I have a feeling that is what you really wanted to ask. *also why did the answerer not list values that are currently working in my python script* because the list of headers is long, and he cut it short by typing `# ... etc. ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

email.message_from_string() just parses the headers from the email. Using keys() you get all present headers from the email.

```
import email

e = """Sender: test@test.dk
From: test@test.dk
HelloWorld: test

test email
"""

a = email.message_from_string(e)

print a.keys()
```

Outputs: ['Sender', 'From', 'HelloWorld']

Therefore, you will never find a manual that includes from, to, sender etc. as they are not part of the API, but just parsed from the headers.